# Stop SASS compiling color to font-color

Tags: css, html, fonts, sass

Pretty straightforward. Im new to sass, but I want my font to be a specific color. I have a mixin

```
@mixin small-headline-font {
font: {
  family:'Open sans', sans-serif;
  size: 24px;
  weight:700;
  color:#052C47; 
  }
}
```

but it compiles to

```
#small-headline {
 font-family: 'Open sans', sans-serif;
 font-size: 24px;
 font-weight: 700;
 font-color: #052C47;
 }
}
```

Font-color is not the correct property name, so how do I keep SASS from compiling color to font-color?

Comment: Perhaps move `color` outside the `font:` bracket?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take it out of the `font{}` brackets:

```
@mixin small-headline-font {
  font: { /* Anything in here will have "font-" prepended */
      family:'Open sans', sans-serif;
      size: 24px;
      weight:700;
  }
  color:#052C47; 
}
```